# How To fetch records from MS ACESS databse table in asp .net using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ms-access-2007

i want to fetch data from MS ACCESS database without reloading the asp .net web page..guys i don't know how to use AJAX in ASP .NET so please help me...thanks in advance...give me some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thre are many solutions on this answer. Two of them you can think about is using

- [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864(v=vs.100).aspx) (i think this is the easing way, but not always the best choice)
- jQuery/AngularJS and a WCF or [WebAPI2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)